# Javascript to resize a browser windows when it has dimension x or y

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need a script that refreshes the browser when the user resizes the windows.

The script should check if the window's size is over a specific dimension (in my case 600px and 800px) and do the refresh only in this case.

This script could also use jQuery.

Can you suggest any ideas or tutorials?

Comment: you can look at jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Out of pure interest, in what kind of situation is this needed?

Comment: I use css media queries to change the layout of a page depending on windows size. In the page I use ORBIT (a jquery plugin), there is some problem when a user change the dimension of the page so refreshing the page seems a reasonable solution thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  var t;
  $(window).resize(function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    if ($(window).width() > 800 && $(window).height() > 600) {
      t = setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload();
      }, 200);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    }   
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mytho, is working! May I ask you how to modify your script so the reload happen when a user release the mouse button after resizing the windows? Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Modified the code to include a timeout function. That should do it.